# Can an adjective follow "more than"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I came across a weird sentence in a paper. I wonder if its phrasing is correct grammatically since it doesn't make much sense to me.

> Since
>   1991, the number of children with a mother in prison more than doubled, up 131% and children
>   with a father in prison increased by 77%.

I have seen no such usage before where an adjective follows "more than". Is there something I don't know about such structure, or that the author has used a grammatically poor statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This usage is correct. Here, *more than* is used with a *verb*. Look at the sentence

> The number of children doubled.

The verb here is "doubled," meaning "increased to a new amount that is twice the original amount".

We can use "more than doubled" to mean "increased to a new amount that is *more than* twice the original amount":

> The number of children more than doubled.

This is a normal use of *more than* for "multiplier" verbs like *double* or *triple*. To confirm this, you can do a [Google search for "more than doubled"](https://encrypted.google.com/#&q=%22more%20than%20doubled%22), which shows the phrase used by Time magazine and official agencies like the CDC.

---

Using *more than* with adjectives is also normal (but that is not what is happening in your example):

> She is more than angry; she is *furious*.
>
> They are more than just strong; they are also very fast and smart.